# Generic UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am trying to create a Repository & UnitOfWork for Data Access Layer. In my current implementation I have to modify my UnitOfWork everytime I create a new repository. I would like to avoid that and also keep the functionality to extend my repository abstract class.

Following is my generic Repository & UnitOfWork interface & classes

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> FindAll();
    T FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    void Create(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected DBContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    public RepositoryBase(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    //other methods removed
    public void Create(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork 
{
    IReminderRepository Reminder { get; }
    void Save();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    protected DBContext _dbContext { get; set; }
    private IReminderRepository _reminderRepository;

    public UnitOfWork(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IReminderRepository Reminder
    {
        get
        {
            return _reminderRepository = _reminderRepository ?? new ReminderRepository(_dbContext);
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here I can extend my Repository as per my specific needs by implementing the specific Repository as

```
public interface IReminderRepository : IRepositoryBase<Reminder>
{
    IList<Reminder> GetAllReminders();
    Reminder GetReminderById(Guid id);    
    Reminder GetReminderByName(string name);    
    void CreateReminder(Reminder reminder);    
    void UpdateReminder(Reminder reminder);    
    void DeleteReminder(Reminder reminder);    
}

public class ReminderRepository : RepositoryBase<Reminder>, IReminderRepository
{
    public ReminderRepository(DBContext dbContext)
    : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    //other methods removed
    public Reminder GetReminderByName(string name)
    {
        return FindAll()
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == name);

        //return FindByCondition(r => r.Name == name);
    }
}
```

This is ok but when ever I will create a new Specific Repository I will have to modify the UnitOfWork class as well by adding a new property for the new Repository.

While searching online I found following but it does not work in my case as my RepositoryBase is an abstract class.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork 
{
    void Save();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext { get; set; }
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Dictionary<Type, object> Repositories
    {
        get { return _repositories; }
        set { Repositories = value; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IRepositoryBase<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (Repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            return Repositories[typeof(T)] as IRepositoryBase<T>;
        }

        IRepositoryBase<T> repo = new RepositoryBase<T>(_dbContext);//This does not work
        Repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
        return repo;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why RepositoryBase have to be abstract ? it shouldn't have to be.
A generic Repository is a good practive for simpe CRUD on simple entity without to specifically create a repository child for that entity who add nothing.

Comment: I presume you have some kind of IoC container. You can register `ReminderRepository`  and then have generic method in your UoW: `GetRepo<T>() => _IoC.GetService<T>()`. You can also register them as `IRepositoryBase<Reminder>` and then cast the repo to specific type if you need those methods

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I am not using any IoC container. I am registering my UnitOfWork class in StartUp.cs file of my WebAPI project as `services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();`

Comment: This is IoC container provided by ASP.

Comment: @Mackhdo, yaa I think I can make `RepositoryBase` as non abstract as well.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek, what do u suggest in this case.

Comment: register also all your repositories and let UoW get them from `services` through generic method

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek, so u also suggest to make `RepositoryBase` as non abstract...

Comment: yes, and then create specialized classes only for entities that need some custom work, like those that have collections of other entitites. To be honest, if you have more than 4 entitiy classes with relations between them, generic repository quckly becomes more and more time consuming and boiler plate. Also, if you really want your UoW do anything more than clutter the code, use `_context.Database.Begin/EndTransaction` in it

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek only reason why m looking @ Repository & UoW is to have the possibility to switch the Repository incase the data source is changed like instead of using EF with SQLServer we start using MongoDB or something else. This way I would only have to rewrite the Repository & UoW and rest everything will remain same. Do u suggest any other Design Pattern keeping in mind data source switching context.

Comment: No, I would suggest sticking with it, but to make it more powerfull. Make UoW JUST for handling transactions (that's the only reason to add this layer), create your repos like @mm8 suggested in his response and stick to EF. With EF you can just switch database server, connection string and driver and everything works, at least until you go NoSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously need to get a reference to a `IReminderRepository` somewhere in your code to be able to use the remainder specific APIs.

If you don't want to extend your `UnitOfWork` class to return an `IReminderRepository`, you may create one yourself in the method that actually uses the specific repository, e.g.:

```
using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
    ReminderRepository repository = new ReminderRepository(context);
    Reminder remainder = repository.GetReminderByName("...");
    remainder.SomeProperty = "updated value..";
    uow.Save();
}
```

The only purpose of using the unit of work is to be able to share the same context between several different repositories anyway. Exposing a `Dictionary<Type, object>` in your `UnitOfWork` won't solve anything as the purpose of using generics is to provide compile-time type safety.

Comment: what I have done is register IUnitOfWork in Startup.cs as `services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();` and then in my Controller am using `_unitOfWork.Reminder.FindAll().ToList();`

Comment: @NikhilGupta: So then `IUnitOfWork` has a `Reminder` property? I thought you wanted to avoid this.

Comment: Yes as of now UoW has Reminder as a property and I would like to get rid of it bcoz in future there can be many such entities and then it will be over head to always modify UoW when introducing a new entity.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Yes. So did you read my answer? It provides an alternative to extending the `UnitOfWork` with repository properties. Just let it call `Save` on the context, and create the repositiories yourself in the DAL where you actually need them.

Comment: and like you suggested that I create the object for `IReminderRepository` in the method that uses it then I will have to register all my repositories in Startup.cs and then using DI I will be able to use them.... is that right?

Comment: You don't need to register them anywhere if you instantiate them directly yourself as per my sample code. You just create an instance of a class as usual.

Comment: what I understand is that now UoW should only have Save and lets say I have a service layer where I use this repository and UoW, there I need to initialize the specific Repository class. To be honest I some how don't feel better with this approach as compared to repository as property :(

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Stick with properties then. But generics isn't the answer to your question. Where are you supposed to define the type argument?

Comment: In my case generic was anyways not working bcoz my `RepositoryBase` is an abstract class which I would like to keep it as is but then in the `Repository` method I can not create an objects of Repository I need. Like in my controller if I do `_unitOfWork.Repository<Reminder>().GetReminderById(id);` then its no longer possible as `GetReminderById` is in `ReminderRepository` and `UoW` only returns object of `RepositoryBase`

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Exactly. It makes no sense to return a `RepositoryBase`. That's why I wrote that you need to get an `IReminderRepository` from somewhere. You have two options. 1. Add properties to your `UnitOfWork` class. 2. Don't add create the respositories as you need them.

Comment: What I would prefer is to use `EF` directly in the `Service layer` and skip the `Repository` & `UoW` but then it lacks the ability to switch off EF and use may b some `cloud DB` r any other data source without completely rewriting the `Service layer`

Comment: EF should be in the DAL only, but this is a different topic. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.